# onClick automatico

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Saludos para todos, de casualidad alguien sabe como se puede hacer que un botón se clickee solo pasados unos segundos.

algo así como en Waze que uno elige la ruta y aparece un Botón (Ir ahora) el cual después de unos segundos se presiona solo activando la ruta deseada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con el metodo `postDelayed` de la clase `Handler`, especificandole el tiempo:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //ejecutas metodo click del boton aqui
  }
}, 1000); // 1000 = 1 segundo
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias Einer

Comment: Funciona muy bien, sabes como podria hacer para que solo se presione una vez quiero que se presione cada vez que entro a la actividad pero solo una vez es que se presiona cada segundo

Answer (score 2):

Para ejecutar el botón usa el método [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()); , para que se ejecute en determinado tiempo usa un Handler, define la cantidad de milisegundos que deseas se ejecute un proceso o en este caso la acción relacionada al clic de un botón:

```
int TIEMPO = 10000; //como ejemplo 10 segundos (10,000 milisegundos)

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Ejecuta clic en boton, metodo o proceso.
                myButton.performClick();

            }
        }, TIEMPO);
```